# How to apply function to row of a dataframe only if it contains less than a certain number of NaNs?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have what I think is an easy question but I'm missing something.

I've got a data frame of values. I want to average the rows... but I only want to do so if it matches a certain number of entries -- or lacks NaN values in other words. So the following dataframe should get an 'average' column of [1.5, 1.5, np.nan], but I'm getting a "truth value of a Series is ambiguous" error. I don't know what that means.

I thought it'd be something like this...

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,np.nan,2], 
              [1, 1.5, 2], 
              [np.nan, np.nan, 1]])

df['mean'] = df[0:3].mean(axis=1) if df['nullsum'] < 2 else np.nan


ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Answer (score 2):

You can drop it firstly then `reindex`, `thresh` in `dropna` means how many notnull values are required

```
df.dropna(thresh=2).mean(1).reindex(df.index)
Out[264]: 
0    1.5
1    1.5
2    NaN
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

As df['nullsum'] is a Series, and such comparison is not possible, it throws an error. You would want to compare the value of nullsum at every row.

```
df['mean']= df.apply(lambda x: np.mean(x[:3]) if x['nullsum'] < 2 else np.nan,axis=1)
```

Here x takes row by row, so x['nullsum'] gives the value at that particular row.